# Sudo: no valid sudoers sources found

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

> `sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
> sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
> sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin`

Что делать? Как исправить?

Answer (score 3):

Убрать права на запись с файла `/etc/sudoers`:

```
chmod a-w /etc/sudoers
```

Если не получится из основной системы, то загрузиться с лайв-сиди и поменять права оттуда

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно из-под учетной записи root выполнить

```
chmod 440 /etc/sudoers
```

Если нет доступа к root, то можете загрузиться в single mode, либо загрузиться с liveCD, и сделать ту же процедуру.