# Исправление последствий "chmod 777 /"

Tags: linux, sudo, chmod

В ubuntu 14 4 выполнил `chmod 777 /`, после чего перестали выполняться `su` и `sudo -s`.

Как это исправить?

```
$ su 
operation not permitted

$ sudo -s
/etc/sudoers is world writable
no valid sudoers souces found, quitting
unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/189971/sudo-no-valid-sudoers-sources-found

Comment: можно ещё поставить систему на соседней виртуалке и сделать автоматическое приведение прав к одному знаменателю простым скриптом

Comment: наверное, вы выполнили `chmod -R 777 /`? В противном случае права изменились бы только у директорий в корне.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

наиболее эффективный, с моей точки зрения, выход из сложившейся ситуации  — сохранение файлов с данными и переустановка системы.

поведение двух упомянутых программ — это лишь самая верхушка «айсберга», остальные последствия будут обнаруживаться позже, в самые, вероятно, неожиданные моменты. из основных «результатов» можно отметить хотя бы пару: во-первых, ваша система сейчас представляет собой «дырявое решето» (с точки зрения безопасности и защищённости системы), во-вторых, некоторые «демоны» могут либо вообще перестать работать (после перезагрузки), либо работать некорректно.

я лично (считая себя далеко не новичком) исправлять последствия такого «вандализма» даже бы не взялся — это адский кропотливый труд.

Comment: Эта тема была очень познавательной

Comment: вы в будущем лучше так не «ошибайтесь». права администратора системы — при неаккуратном обращении — могут стать весьма разрушительными.

Answer (score 3):

Можно ещё поставить систему на соседней виртуалке и сделать автоматическое приведение прав к одному знаменателю простым скриптом.

На виртуалке:

```
find / |xargs stat -c "chmod %a %n" > /rights-1.txt # Создаёт файл где сохранены права и названия с путем 
find / |xargs stat -c "chown %U:%G %n" > /rights-2.txt # Создаёт файл с принадлежностями и путём
```

Перенести эти файлы на основную систему и просто выполнить:

```
bash </rights-1.txt 
bash </rights-2.txt
```

Comment: огромное количество файлов этот совет не затронет.

Comment: не все, но если поставить все такие же пакеты, то большинство. Остальные - кастомные, значит пользовательсам разберётся, так как ставил их сам. Системные будут восстановлены.

Comment: увы, очень многие «демоны» создают файлы/каталоги в процессе работы. получить полную копию проработавшей какое-то время и использовавшейся системы (с точностью до файла/каталога), к сожалению, практически невозможно.

Comment: жаль, мне уже начала нравиться идея со скриптом

Comment: В любом случае, "адский кропотливый труд", если другого выбора не останется с моим решением сильно уменьшится. Я не претендую на лучшее решение, просто если идти путём восстановления, а не переустановки, то я вижу свой способ лучшем из простых. 

Если кто-то где-то достанет все возможные права на файлы в Ubuntu для любого утанавливаемого сервиса, базы данных и тд, это будет лучшим решением, чем моё.

Comment: @mr_blond97, идея неплоха в том смысле, что может существенно сократить временные затраты по восстановлению системы. но и оставшаяся часть работы, с моей точки зрения, для человека, недосконально понимающего все тонкости организации системы прав, остаётся весьма значительной. пользователю со средним уровнем познаний я бы лично рекомендовал переустановку. и сам бы выбрал именно этот путь (из соображений экономии времени).

Comment: @mr_blond97, элементарное соображение: вы проделаете почти идентичную часть работы (установку и настройку новой системы, установку правильных прав на файлы/каталоги с данными), но вместо копирования данных будет: 1. довольно длительная процедура синхронизации прав и 2. неизвестно сколько займущая процедура поиска и восстановления прав у файлов, которых не будет в «образцовой» системе.

Comment: @alexander barakin, да, работы придется проделать не меньше чем при настройке новой системы

Answer (score 2):

Из-под root

chmod 440 /etc/sudoers

Comment: а как же байт `s` у файлов `/bin/su` и `/usr/bin/sudo`? а сотни тысяч ставших доступными для записи всем файлов? а как же десятки (может и сотни) файлов и каталогов, у которых сброшены другие спец-аттрибуты?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Вопрос был про восстановление доступа к sudo, а не про то, что делать с остальными файлами.

Comment: @HermannZheboldov думаю, раз топикстартер указал причину, значит он предполагает, как и предполагаем мы, что данная проблема появилась не случайно и возможно будет не единственной. Намекая на комплексное решение проблемы.

Comment: @HermannZheboldov, увы, даже для восстановления работоспособности одной программы `/usr/bin/sudo` вашего ответа недостаточно. // кстати, строка «из-под root» в ответе — излишняя. выполнить указанную команду может любой пользователь системы (после описанного «вандализма»).

Answer (score 1):

Указанная команда не могла нанести такого вреда, по-видимому был ещё ключ `-R`.

Можно переустановить все установленные пакеты, при этом восстановятся и права, кроме файлов и каталогов не относящихся к пакетам.
Для систем с *дебиановским менеджером пакетов*:

```
# apt-get --reinstall install `dpkg --get-selections | grep install | grep -v deinstall | cut -f1`
```

Если при этом будет невозможно переустановить какие-то пакеты, их можно пропустить добавив имена в фильтр:

```
# apt-get --reinstall install `dpkg --get-selections | grep install | grep -v deinstall | cut -f1 | egrep -v '(package1|package2)'`
```

Источник: http://hyperlogos.org/page/Restoring-Permissions-Debian-System

Если в систему нельзя войти как root, придётся загрузиться с флэшки. и сделать `chroot` на раздел с испорченной системой.

Comment: Попробовал в виртуалке — неа, у многих (но не у всех) файлов из пакетов права всё равно не вернулись