# Chmod. Разблокирование прав

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

Я новичок в Ubuntu  и случайно ,в терминале  , в домашнем каталоге 
 (там где bin и самые важные файлы) вместо команды sudo chmod 777 -R ввёл sudo chmod 77 -R,как я понял , я полностью заблокировал убунту , потому что при перезагрузки появилась вот такая картинка с текстом что с ваша видеокарта не была найдена.Как мне разблокировать убунту ?P.S Версия убунту 16.04 ЛТС и все остальные папки,файлы которые были мною заблокированные.

Comment: У вас установлен pkexec?

Comment: @DmitryKalinin Нет,я даже не знаю что это

Comment: судя по тому, что вы пишете в комментариях, команду вы выполнили не в домашнем каталоге. тогда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/484517/178576

Comment: Разные команды , у меня 77 , а там 777 / , а ещё  , что самое странное у меня даже убунту не видит видеокарту

Comment: какой именно аргумент вы передали программе chmod — не играет абсолютно никакой роли. важно — у каких объектов файловой системы вы изменили права доступа. если только в каталоге /bin — это несложно исправить. если в каталоге / — читайте мой ответ по приведённой выше ссылке.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Извините , я новичок , могу ошибаться , но ведь chmode - это команда , которая меняет права в зависимости от его значения (777 , 755 ,666 и тд.)

Comment: не играет абсолютно никакой роли, под какую именно «гребёнку» вы «причесали» **разные** наборы битов. роль играют лишь масштабы вашего «вандализма».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin А если вернуть root-права как показано в ответе снизу , это ведь более чем реально сделать , не так ли?

Comment: я привёл ссылку выше. удачи!

Comment: Блин , самое обидное , что мой ubuntu прожил 1 час 45 минут с момента загрузки . RIP 05.11.2017 - 05.11.2017. Я даже не знал что так легко можно убить эту операционную систему

Comment: *так легко* — да, обладая административными правами. на то они и административные права. а бездумное повторение чьих-то вредных советов — самый быстрый к этому путь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шаг 1: Запустите режим recovery mode

Шаг 2: В режиме recovery mode, нужно выбрать **root - Drop to root shell prompt**

Шаг 3: Запустите команды:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
reboot
```

Comment: @Dmity Kalinin Если это работает  ,спасибо огромное , но что такое recovery mode , как его запустить?

Comment: shift держи вдавленным во время загрузки, а потом в меню grub. Там и выбор recovery mode.

Comment: Во время загрузки убунту , или сразу же при запуске ?

Comment: После перезагрузки.

Comment: Чего именно?Убунту я та запустить не могу , могу , но там всё заблокировано , ничего не работает , в загрузчике он есть .

Comment: Вам в нее заходить и не нужно, перезагрузите компьютер и жмите shift

Comment: Как я делаю : 1. Выключаю комп . 2. Включаю 3. В загрузчике выбираю Ubuntu и зажимаю shift . 4. У меня выскакивает консоль просит пароль и логин , ввожу , и потом потом просто командная строка появляется.Ввожу первую команду - ошибка что я не руут.