# Применение прав ко всем файлам сервера 777,как восстановить доступ к серверу?

Tags: django, ssh, sftp, filezilla, yandex-cloud

столкнулся с такой проблемой ,есть сервер на яндекс облаке,на него захожу через ssh ключ,так как по паролю там нельзя.С помощью filezilla хотел перенести проект на сервер, но не было прав на запись файлов,и я совершил ошибку выставив права на все файлы на сервере 777.После этого программа отключилась от сервера и никак не заходит, отклоняя ssh ключ(т.к. у меня windows7 то заходил через winscp).Можно ли как то восстановить доступ к серверу?Через серийную консоль яндекса пробовал, но там требует логин и пароль(который нигде не создавался,потому что требовался только public ssh).

Comment: Обратиться в службу поддержки. Или удалить сервер и создать новый.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/484535/178576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть метод через снимок и дополнительную машину -> [тут](https://nikolaymatrosov.medium.com/%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-ssh-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-yandex-cloud-205858a96e6e)

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)